# c# logic not correct simple windows form

Tags: logic

I am trying to help my brother out with one of his assignments for a course.

The task:

[IMGUR link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWt64.png)

This is his code for the c# windows form

```
double sec;
double min;
double hour;
double day;

sec = double.Parse(secondsTb.Text);
min = sec / 60;
hour = sec / 3600;
day = sec / 86400;
hour = (60 * min) / 60;
day = (24 * hour) / 24;

if (sec >= 60)
MessageBox.Show(min.ToString() + " minutes");
else if (sec >= 3600)
MessageBox.Show(hour.ToString() + " hours");
else if (sec >= 86400)
MessageBox.Show(day.ToString() + "days");
```

I believe there is a mistake with his >= logic in each of the statements but I am not quite sure how to fix it.

The program is stuck with the first if, and it correctly transforms the output to minutes, but when a greater value for example 3600 or 86400 is typed the program still displays in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the logic. If largest 1st. Then else if until lowest.

If the seconds are 3600, they are indeed greater than 60, which will satisfy your first test, and not test for nor trigger your two additional options.